# How to get acf post object value with date filter in elementor WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am using Elementor Pro in WordPress. Where I want to get data of ACF Field **Post Object** multiselect values with date filter for Upcoming courses.

**ACF Fields**

[image: ACF Fields]

**In page**

[image]

**Edit Post Setting In Elementor**

[image]

**function.php file code**

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/our_courses_with_upcoming_courses', function( $query ) {
  
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'up_coming_course_starttime' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

});
```

`up_coming_course_starttime` - is startdate acf parameter

**This is current result** - currently all course are coming

[image]

So How to get list only selected courses from multiselect and I want also add filter of that date all list will come with upcoming dates only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try below `jQuery ID` function. May be it's helpful.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/our_courses_with_upcoming_courses', function( $query ) {
    $course_date = rses = get_field( "select_related_upcoming_courses" );
    
    if($upcoming_courses && count($upcoming_courses) > 0){
      $query->set( 'post__in', $upcoming_courses );
    }
    if($course_date) {
          $middle = strtotime($course_date);
          $new_date = date('Ymd', $middle);

         get_field( "select_our_course_date" );
    $upcoming_cou $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
              array(
                  'key'     => 'up_coming_course_starttime',
                  'value'    => $new_date,
                  'compare' => '>=',
              ),
          ) );
     }

    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'up_coming_course_starttime' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

  });
```

Comment: I have almost the same problem. My courses have an ACF filed with `course_date` and I need only the upcoming courses. But I think your code example has some typos!? I can't reproduce it. The `rses` gives me an error or the variabale `upcoming_courses` is anywhere defined!? Maybe you can fix the code so I can maybe use it? Thanks a lot.